# Bluemix security roles

Tags: forms, jsf, authentication, ibm-cloud, security-roles

I just started learning about Bluemix and am slightly confused.

I am currently building a form-based login authentication with JSF which will be used in a web application that works on Bluemix.

How will I change security related settings in Bluemix? Locally, I can change in an admin console of my application server but I have no idea how to in Bluemix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to upload your server.xml with your app to bluemix.

If you use eclipse, on your local server, right mouse click --> utilities --> package server.

Next push the resulting zip to bluemix using the cf command line.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jcyr24ldTys) shows each step

Answer (score 1):

Check out this pdf on docs for how to integrate Single Sign On with your java app.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27044519&aid=1

Answer (score 0):

Are you considering use oauth to meet your requeiment? In Bluemix, you can use App User Registry to protect your resources, and client need to get token first to access your resources. 
Take a look at my developerWorks paper to get more details: Protect your resources with the Bluemix App User Registry Add-on, the link is : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-oauthregistry-app/index.html
Hope this can help you.

Comment: Did you use the way I moneitoned above?